# Django Rest Framework. SerializerMethodField or source?

Tags: django, rest, optimization, serialization, django-rest-framework

Question about DRF serializers. Especially ModelSerializer.

There are two versions with Foreign Key:

1. `field = CharField(source='user.name')`
2. `field = SeriaizerMethodField()
   get_field(self, obj):
       return obj.user.name`

What will work better / quickly ?

**UPD**

yes, I know about select/prefetch_related. 
But is better just to pull required field from database and serialized it automaticaly or pull some 'raw' fields and nicely join them in serializer?

Comment: [Race the horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no difference between them. If you want to improve speed you should do it in a view by calling `select_related` method of a queryset.

```
YourModel.objects.select_related('user')
```

It'll join `user` table and calling `user.name` atribute will not hit a database next time

Answer (score 0):

[First one](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) provides different validation options from the box. While the second one is something very customizable and doesn't provide any validation itself.